# How to specify which interface an application uses?

Tags: linux, networking

Imagine this example: you have direct access to the internet on `eth0`, and you have a VPN on `tun0`.

You want one application to access the internet directly through `eth0` (using X public IP address) and another application to access the internet through `tun0` (using Y public IP).

Comment: Can you try expanding on your question? It's a little hard to follow what you're asking for and what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: bind on a specific ip address

Comment: The VPN probably changes your routing table. Have you tried `route -n` ?

Comment: All interfaces _are_ this machine...

Comment: @vonbrand Even if they are, binds can listen to particular interface. If you set your socket to listen on `127.0.0.1`, you can only accept incoming loopback connections. Lots of web development servers do that. To listen everywhere you can bind to address `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: As others note, an application can pick an interface on which to _listen_. I think you're asking the opposite: Can a _client_ choose which network interface to use when establishing a connection with a remote listener? The answer is that the client's connect() call will end up using the route (and interface) defined by the routing table. There may be application specific approaches to achieve this, such as two web browsers using different networks via choosing proxy servers within one or the other network.  Did I interpret your question correctly?

Comment: An application can bind to an *interface* too (SO_BINDTODEVICE), but interaction with routing might not be always as expected. See this Q/A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177398/connect-through-different-interfaces-to-the-same-server-so-bindtodevice-desti