# Connect through different interfaces to the same server (SO_BINDTODEVICE): Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: routing, socket

I have 2 interfaces: `eth0` and `wlan0`, each one connected to a different router. Their network specs are these:

```
eth0:
    ip: 192.168.1.7
    Gateway: 192.168.1.1
    Submask: 255.255.255.0

wlan0:
    ip: 192.168.2.21
    Gateway: 192.168.2.1
    Submask: 255.255.255.0
```

I've configured the routing this way:

```
ip route add table eth0 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 scope link
ip route add table eth0 default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
ip rule add from 192.168.1.7 table eth0
```

And the same for wlan0 using his values. So the routing output is:

```
ip rule
    0:      from all lookup local
    32764:  from 192.168.2.21 lookup wlan0
    32765:  from 192.168.1.7 lookup eth0
    32766:  from all lookup main
    32767:  from all lookup default

ip r s
    default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static
    192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.7  metric 1
    192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.21  metric 9

ip r s table eth0
    default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
    192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  scope link

ip r s table wlan0
    default via 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0
    192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0  scope link
```

And also changed `sysctl "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0"` and `sysctl -w "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1"`. (Don't really think that `ip_forward` is needed but I've changed it just in case).

Now, the weird thing is that when I ping Google forcing interface `wlan0` it says `Destination Host Unreachable`. The other interface works fine.

```
ping -I wlan0 google.es
    PING google.es (173.194.45.183) from 192.168.2.21 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 192.168.2.21 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 192.168.2.21 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 192.168.2.21 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 192.168.2.21 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

ping -I eth0 google.es
    PING google.es (173.194.45.191) from 192.168.1.7 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from mad06s09-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.45.191): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=21.5 ms
    64 bytes from mad06s09-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.45.191): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=21.7 ms
    64 bytes from mad06s09-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.45.191): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=24.6 ms
    64 bytes from mad06s09-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.45.191): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=31.1 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how the source address determination is done in case of such a forced interface binding. If the source address is not taken from the device then the problem is that your `ip rule` selectors don't match so that the packet runs into the `main` routing table i.e.

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static
```

which doesn't work from `wlan0`.

I suggest you try this:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.7  table  eth0
ip rule add oif  eth0         table  eth0
ip rule add from 192.168.2.21 table wlan0
ip rule add oif  wlan0        table wlan0
```

and extend the

```
ip route add table eth0
ip route add table wlan0
```

commands by the `src` option.

Comment: Oh my god! This is working!!!! 3 days with this trying tons of different configurations and you come with this perfect solution. Can you, please, explain why this worked? I have lost so much time with this and want to learn something about it (don't really understand the 'source address determination' thing). Thank you again!

Comment: Ok, just checked and`oif` is what does the trick. Thank you again!