# Connect through different interfaces to the same server

Tags: networking, network-interface, route, ppp

i have two pppoe interfaces - `ppp0` and `ppp1`. I would like to reach the same server on both interface. I added the desired ip address to the route table:

```
route add 10.88.40.13 ppp0
```

And I could reach the server. But when I want to add this destination IP to the other interface as well:

```
route add 10.88.40.13 ppp1

kittlnx127:~ # route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.62.49.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.62.49.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.88.40.13     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp1
loopback        *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.203.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.203.1   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp1
192.168.201.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

So the entry is updated with the new interface.
The two interface have different source IP addresses:

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.43.154.48  P-t-P:169.254.203.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:80 (80.0 b)  TX bytes:80 (80.0 b)

ppp1      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:10.43.154.32  P-t-P:169.254.203.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:80 (80.0 b)  TX bytes:80 (80.0 b)
```

So is it possible somehow to reach the same server on both interfaces? Should I give more details? Thanks in advance! I found this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177398/connect-through-different-interfaces-to-the-same-server-so-bindtodevice-desti) but I think this not the same case...

Comment: probably I dont need this scenario anymore

Answer (score 1):

I thing what you're looking for is called **Network Interface Bonding**

See, for example http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ch11s05.html

Comment: probably I dont need this scenario anymore - but thanks for your effort